# SQL query to INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql

**asset_property** table:

```
| asset_id | property_id | property_value |
|:--------:|:-----------:|:---------------|
| 146      | 1           | 4G             |
| 146      | 3           | 68723-239Gs    |
| 147      | 1           | A7             |
```

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO asset_property (asset_id, property_id, property_value)
VALUES
  (146, 1, '4G'),
  (146, 2, 'Black & Decker'),
  (146, 3, ''),
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE property_value = VALUES(property_value);
```

Is there a way to say something like this:

```
INSERT INTO asset_property (asset_id, property_id, property_value)
VALUES
  (146, 1, '4G'),
  (146, 2, 'Black & Decker'),
  (146, 3, ''),
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE property_value = VALUES(property_value)
ON VALUES(property_value) IS NULL
DELETE FROM asset_property
WHERE asset_id = VALUES(asset_id)
AND property_id = VALUES(property_id);
```

Or I could use PHP to determine empty `property_value` sets and build a second query. So I would need this:

```
DELETE FROM asset_property
WHERE 'PRIMARY KEY' IN ('146-3');
```

The syntax is okay, but 0 rows are affected.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT 'PRIMARY KEY' FROM asset_property WHERE asset_id = 146;
```

But the result is:

```
| PRIMARY KEY |
|:------------|
| PRIMARY KEY |
| PRIMARY KEY |
```

The [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) seams to say you can't.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? why are you selecting 'PRIMARY KEY' as a string?

Comment: I didn't realize the single quotes designated a string _:/_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM asset_property
WHERE 'PRIMARY KEY' IN ('146-3');
```

> The syntax is okay, but 0 rows are affected.

There aren't any syntax errors, but that doesn't mean it's okay :) @rodrigoap has already explained what that one means, and why 0 rows match.

If you need to delete several records matching a composite primary key, you're going to have to do one of these:

```
DELETE FROM asset_property
WHERE (asset_id = 146 AND property_id = 3)
   OR (asset_id = 146 AND property_id = 7)
   OR (asset_id = 146 AND property_id = 18)
```

or concatenate the fields and test that:

```
DELETE FROM asset_property
WHERE CONCAT(asset_id, '-', property_id) in ('146-3', '146-7', '146-18')
```

(this one will be slower, because it can't take advantage of any indexes)

or just execute multiple delete statements inside of a transaction:

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM asset_property
WHERE asset_id = 146 AND property_id = 3
DELETE FROM asset_property
WHERE asset_id = 146 AND property_id = 7
DELETE FROM asset_property
WHERE asset_id = 146 AND property_id = 18
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM asset_property
 WHERE 'PRIMARY KEY' IN ('146-3');
```

Deletes 0 rows because the where clause is false, the text 'PRIMARY KEY' is not in the list ('146-3').

```
SELECT 'PRIMARY KEY' FROM asset_property WHERE asset_id = 146;
```

This one is returning the text 'PRIMARY KEY' for each row in the table asset_property where asset_id is 146.

Comment: Is there sytax for specifying a specific PRIMARY KEY? Something _like 143-3_? I now realize that 'PRIMARY KEY' isn't actually referencing _the_ `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

So, your `PRIMARY KEY` is composed from `asset_id` and `property_id`?. In that case you can do your `DELETE` like this:

```
DELETE FROM asset_property
WHERE asset_id = 146 AND property_id = 3
```

Comment: I need to use `IN (...)` because I can delete multiple records at once: `IN ('146-3', '146-7', '146-18')`. Otherwise I'm stuck with a separate query for each case of a blank field.